# How do you send files to the OpenAI API?

Tags: rust, documentation, openai-api

For fun I wanted to try to make a tool to ask chatgpt to document rust files. I found an issue, in that the maximum message length the API allows seems to be 2048 characters.

It seems that the OpenAI API [allows you to send files](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files), so I was hoping that by sending  the files to the server the model would have the context it needs to generate the comments.

However, I don't seem to be able to do so, I tried this:

```rs
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

use chatgpt::prelude::*;
use clap::Parser;
use syn;
use syn::Item;
use reqwest;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args
{
    /// Path to the source code to document
    #[arg(short, long)]
    file_path: String,
}

fn main()
{
    let args = Args::parse();

    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(args.file_path).unwrap();
    let mut content = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut content).unwrap();

    let ast = syn::parse_file(&content).unwrap();
    let mut input_buffer = String::new();

    // Getting the API key here
    let key = "My key that I have replaced for obvious reasons";

    {
        // Create a reqwest client
        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

        // Make a POST request to the OpenAI API
        let response = client
            .post("https://api.openai.com/v1/files")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer My key that I have replaced for obvious reasons")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(content.clone())
            .send().unwrap();

        // Check if the request was successful
        if response.status().is_success() {
            println!("File uploaded successfully!");
        } else {
            println!("Failed to upload file. Status code: {}", response.status());
        }

        std::mem::forget(client);
        std::mem::forget(response);
    }
}
```

The response I get is:

`Failed to upload file. Status code: 415 Unsupported Media Type`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have also tried changign the content type to `text/plain`, I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe `application/json` is not supported MIME type?

Comment: That is the default that appears int he documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`async-openai`](https://crates.io/crates/async-openai) crate has [`Files`](https://docs.rs/async-openai/0.18.3/async_openai/struct.Files.html), which allows you to upload files to OpenAI:

```
let client = Client::new();
let request = CreateFileRequest {
    input: "path/to/my/file.bin".into(),
    purpose: "test".into(),
};
let response = client.files().create (request).await?;
```

Comment: This allows you to get the file to OpenAI as a hole but not to a specific assistant

Comment: Your question didn't mention linking the file to a specific assistant. For that you can use [`AssistantFiles`](https://docs.rs/async-openai/0.18.3/async_openai/struct.AssistantFiles.html)